# Auto increment of a selected column with a header

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Serial()
Dim SerialNum() As Variant
Dim Selected As Range
Set Selected = Selection

ReDim SerialNum(1 To 26, 1) As Variant

Dim k As Integer
SerialNum(1, 1) = "Serial"

For k = 1 To 25
    SerialNum(k + 1, 1) = k
Next k

Selected.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(26, 1).Value = SerialNum
End Sub
```

All I am trying to do here is Print a column next to my selection that shows Header as "Serial" and increments the value until the 26th row or any given number of my choice.
Appreciate any guidance on what am I missing here. New to Macro.

All I receive is blank all the way through not sure what I am doing wrong here.

When I tried this I see Serial all the way through

```
Sub Serial()
Dim SerialNum As Variant
Dim Selected As Range
Set Selected = Selection

ReDim SerialNum(1 To 26) As Variant

Dim k As Integer
SerialNum(1) = "Serial"

For k = 1 To 25
    SerialNum(k + 1) = k
Next k

Selected.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(26).Value = SerialNum
End Sub
```

Comment: I am running this on Microsoft Visual Basic xlsm 2016 file. I am using .Value.

Comment: I tried Dim SerialNum As Variant and I still see a blank.

Comment: `ReDim SerialNum(1 To 26, 1 to 1) As Variant` in your initial snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked! So, I need to mention the columns the same way as the rows. Lesson learned.

Comment: The problem is that `Redim SerialNum(1 to 6, 1)` here is equivalent to
`ReDim SerialNum(1 To 26, 0 to 1)`.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So much to learn about VB.

Comment: Always explicitly define both the lower and upper bounds of any array - especially more so when working in Excel, where a `Range` maps to a 1-based 2D variant array while implicitly-bound arrays are 0-based by default (unless `Option Base 1` is specified, but don't do that - just specify explicit bounds and you're good).